# Stopping docker container from generating logs when fluentd logging driver is used

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, dockerfile, fluent

I am forwarding my docker containers log to fluentd at remote location. I do not want container to generate logs anymore locally on the same machine ( just to avoid storage/ space consumption).
Following is my configuration in docker-compose file for my services.

```
    logging:
      driver: fluentd
      options:
        fluentd-address: dev-fluentd_ip.com:2224
```

Is there any way to stop docker containers to stop generating logs locally?

Comment: You can periodically delete the container log in `var/lib/docker/containers/YourContainerID` with cron

Comment: Agreed @protrafree!! That is one option but in log forwarding everything from container should be passed to the remote location( log collector ) isn't it? I am not sure whether fluentd works like that. Could you please suggest any alternatives here?

Comment: You forward docker container log to fluentd with reading log file and send it?